# Simple XmlHttpRequest AJAX not outputting desired status code

Tags: xmlhttprequest

My first and very simple AJAX request not outputting "status 200 OK".. and instead outputs "0" .. What's wrong?

```
function doit(){
var httpxml = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpxml.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(httpxml.readyState == 4) {
    alert(httpxml.status);
        }
    }
httpxml.open("GET", "http://localhost/test/ROUGH/TEST.php", true);
httpxml.send(null);
}
doit();
```

Comment: Where are you running the code above from?  XmlHttpRequest adheres to the same-origin policy, so the code needs to run from the same origin as the server (in this case, localhost).

Comment: ok that did it.. i had to run it through the webserver ok.. now is there any workaround? (because i might need to use this code in chrome extension developing and there the file runs locally as background.html.. so would it work if I call externally through xmlhttp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for status 0 is that it has run from the disk and not through a webserver.